# Memory leak when assigning to a Record

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, fastmm

Whilst trying to work out why one of our new applications is crashing I've been chasing down memory leaks in Delphi.

I've hooked up the lastest version of [FastMM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/) and have been working through the results, but am confused by the following, which I've boiled down to bare bones for sake of brevity.

We have a record defined with 2 string fields.  These are assigned from two TEdit boxes, and at the same time we write the data to a TListView.  Here is the key code:

```
procedure TForm1.SetAssignment;
var
   tp: TestPointer;
   SourceTable, SourceColumn: string;
   LI: TListItem;
begin
   SourceTable := Edit1.Text;
   SourceColumn := Edit2.Text;
   LI := lvTest.Items.Add;
   LI.Caption := SourceTable;
   LI.SubItems.Add(SourceColumn);
   new(tp);
   // Leak occurs here
   tp^.SourceTable := SourceTable;
   tp^.SourceField := SourceColumn;
   // No leak if preceding lines are ommitted
   TestList.Add(tp);
end;
```

The issue seems to be with with the value of `SourceTable/SourceColumn`, or with the tp^. values.

The TList is being properly cleaned out when we quite: If we comment out the assignments to `tp^.SourceTable/tp^.SourceField` then there is no memory leak.

Maybe it's just because it's the New Year, but I can't see how I release the SourceTable/SourceColumn...

Comment: Please show the code for cleaning up the `TList`. You likely are NOT finalizing each record so the compiler frees its String members. You can alternatively set each String member to `''` before freeing the record itself.

Comment: Also see [Finalize](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Finalize)

Comment: "The TList is being properly cleaned out " - if you cannot find the error, there is no point in blindly believing your words and assumptions. the very fact of bug proves that one of your assumptions is false. So - "doubt everything" (c) Descartes. You quoted the code from `new(tp);` until `TestList.Add(tp);` - no please show the counterpart from `undo  TestList.Add(tp);` to `undo new(tp)` and let us us look if code "being properly| with fresh eyes. Your code is not "being properly" - it leaks. That is the fact to start digging from. So - show please the actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that your clean up code calls FreeMem rather than Dispose on the pointer. That's the only thing I can imagine that has those symptoms. FreeMem just frees the memory, but Dispose will also finalize the contents before freeing.

When you call Dispose you must supply a correctly typed pointer. For your case you must pass a TestPointer to Dispose.